# Ceres-solver Install: CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX 260 Not working

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm trying to install ceres-solver on a work computer where I'm limited by the MAX_PATH length in Windows10 (260). I'm NOT allowed to increase the max path limit on the OS (unfortunately - I tried negotiating with IT). When running Cmake, it will generate lots of files and folders inside

`build\internal\ceres\ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.dir\ Release\ba_iters.5B2CC283.tlog\ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.lastbuildstate`

Build error is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(382,5): error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.dir\
Release\ba_iters.5B2CC283.tlog\ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.lastbuildstate". Path: ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.dir\Release\ba_iters.5B2CC283.tlog\ba_iterschur_acceleratespar
se_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.lastbuildstate exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters. [R:\Data\ceres4\ceres-solver\build-x64-Dynamic\internal\ceres\generated_bundle_adjustment_tes
ts\ba_iterschur_acceleratesparse_clustjacobi_auto_threads_test.vcxproj]
```

As you can see this file path becomes very long and I'm getting errors to stay under 260 characters.

I tried adding this in the CMakeLists.txt of ceres-solver:

```
if (WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX 260 CACHE INTERNAL "Max path length")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX is set to: ${CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX}")
endif()
```

without success. I note that the CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX has been noted into my CmakeCache.txt and it is indeed in there:

```
//Max path length
CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX:INTERNAL=260
```

I'm looking for help on how to fix the compilation issue. I'm rather inexperienced with editing a CMakeLists.txt of a 1000 lines, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try setting `CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX` to a smaller value (but no less than 128).